# Upgrading from Xubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 has disabled my compose key, which I now can't set to its old default

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, 22.04, xfce, compose-key

This is the menu for changing your compose key. It was originally set to "Use system default", but since the upgrade to Xubuntu 22.04, it has disabled my compose key. Now that I want to return it to [Ubuntu's default](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Compose_key), i.e. the "Hold Shift, then AltGR (the order matters), then release, then press what you want to compose" behavior that I had in 20.04, I see no option for this.

[image]

How can I restore the 20.04 behavior?

Comment: What are these two images? To confirm: you want Shift + Right Alt (Right Alt = AltGr)

Comment: @Esther Those two images are two screenshots from Xubuntu's keyboard menu. I want Ubuntu's default compose key behavior, which is "Hold Shift, *then* AltGR (the order matters)".

Comment: I accidentally added a letter to the link. Here is your answer: https://linux.codidact.com/posts/287064

Comment: @Quasímodo That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your configuration to fit your needs, primarily modifying the config file /etc/default/keyboard as says below in cited text.

For valid options for compose variable check

```
$ grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```

also check man pages for `keyboard` and keyboard configuration guide from x.org
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration and
https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Config.html

> Xubuntu with XFCE and LXDE [all versions to 14.04]
>
> For Xubuntu 8.10, edit /etc/default/console-setup; for Xfce4 in Ubuntu
> 12.04.2 the file in question is /etc/default/keyboard. You will see a line containing the keyword XKBOPTIONS. Edit the line to read:
>
> ```
> XKBOPTIONS="compose:rwin"
> ```
>
> (again, replace rwin by ralt if you prefer AltGr as the compose key;
> also Shift+AltGr as it will definitely not clash with other settings)
> A restart of the Xserver (logout) will be required to effect the
> change.
>
> XIM
>
> The Gnome hard coding can be overruled in favour of the original
> Xwindow Input Method (XIM) by setting the environment variable
> GTK_IM_MODULE. This can be set in the /etc/environment file, but if
> the machine has more than one user then it is best set from the home
> directory on a per user basis by modifying ~/.gnomerc or ~/.Xsession
>
> export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
>
> Look at /usr/share/X11/locale/compose.dir to find the appropriate
> compose table for your locale, eg:
>
> ```
> #       This file contains compose table file names.  The first word is the
> #       compose table file name and the second word is the full locale
> #       name.
> #... en_US.UTF-8/Compose             en_GB.UTF-8
> ```
>
> then looking at /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
>
> ```
> # UTF-8 (Unicode) compose sequence
> #... 
> <Multi_key> <p> <exclam>          : "¶"   paragraph # PILCROW SIGN 
> <Multi_key> <P> <exclam>          : "¶"   paragraph # PILCROW SIGN 
> <Multi_key> <plus> <minus>        : "±"   plusminus # PLUS-MINUS SIGN 
> <Multi_key> <question> <question> : "¿"   questiondown # INVERTED QUESTION MARK 
> <Multi_key> <minus> <d>           : "đ"   dstroke # LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE
> ```
>
> <Multi_Key> is the Compose (Shift+AltGr) key
>
> To create your own set of compose keys copy the file
> /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose (or if you prefer the
> equivalent file for your locale) to your home directory as .XCompose
> # cp /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose ~/.XCompose  and edit this file.
>
> Unicode composition
>
> Another means to enter non-keycap characters is to enter them as
> Unicode character number.
>
> Press Shift+Ctrl+U, release U, enter the hexadecimal
> (0123456789abcdef) Unicode character code point, then release
> Shift+Ctrl. An underlined u followed by the number will be displayed
> as you type.
>
> Alternatively, press (and release) Shift+Ctrl+U, then, while
> underlined u is displayed, enter the hexadecimal Unicode character
> code point followed by .
>
> ```
> Shift+Ctrl+U 00f4   ô   (&ocirc;) 
> Shift+Ctrl+U 2203   ∃  (&exist;)
> ```

from official help docs https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#XIM

Comment: Those instructions are clearly specific to Gnome. Are you confident that they work on Xubuntu?

Comment: I don't think that these are the correct instructions even for Gnome. They appear to be designed for changing the result of using your compose key rather than the key itself.

Comment: Instructions are compatible with X11 display manager. If you want to check whether x11 is installed, run dpkg -l | grep xorg. If you want to check if x11 is currently running (if logged in) then run echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

Comment: So where do these instructions tell you where to change your compose key? `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` lets you make new *compose sequences*. Those assume that you've already got your compose key set to the desired value.

Comment: at the beginning on modifying the file /etc/default/keyboard

Comment: By the way, initially on settings/keyboard/compose key value should be at first as layout default, and logout or reboot may be needed.

Comment: Nothing in `grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` seems to resemble `shift + altgr`. https://i.imgur.com/l8hftga.png

Comment: Apparently in this version isn't available, it could be however more pragmatic to use a single key as compose rather than a combination.