# How do I find what my compose key is currently set to?

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, 22.04, xfce, compose-key

As discussed in [a previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428005/), my compose key on Xubuntu 22.04 isn't set to Ubuntu's default. This means that I don't know what it's set to. How can I find out?

Answer (score 3):

#### Xkbcomp

```
% xkbcomp "$DISPLAY" - | grep -B5 Multi_key
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [           Print,         Sys_Req ]
};
key <RALT> {
    type= "TWO_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1]= [       Multi_key,       Multi_key ]
```

The `-B5` argument shows 5 lines before the match. It might be that not all will be needed though; here the answer is **RALT** (right alt).

#### Xmodmap + Xev

```
% xmodmap -pke | grep Multi_key
keycode 108 = Multi_key Multi_key Multi_key Multi_key
```

Then run `xev | grep -w 'keycode 108'` and hit all the keys until you find the one which gets some output. There may be some non-monkey alternative but I don't know it.

Comment: Oh dear. `xkbcomp "$DISPLAY" - | grep -B5 Multi_key` returns nothing at all.

Comment: @J.Mini This may not work on Wayland, only on X